# Sleep thread from another one

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Given two threads A and B, is there any portable way that A can suspend B, without any custom code in B for that purpose?

Rationale: currently, B is a very complicated algorithm, which should cleanly exit when A (a monitoring thread) tells it to, by checking some shared flag from time to time. The problem is that for debugging purposes I would like to know exactly in which state B is the moment A requests such an exit (e.g. to see where we forgot to check the shared flag), so I would like to pause B (for debugging) from A. In other words, I need to not only synchronize the threads, but synchronize debugging the threads.

Comment: You can do that via the debugger. In Visual Studio, simply right click on a thread and select `freeze`. I'm sure GDB has similar capabilities

Comment: While not technically a "pause", consider killing the process from within A with SIGSEGV and examining the core dump.

Comment: @jalf: in that case it would be almost impossible to get the state <at the moment> that A sets the flag

Comment: @BroesDeCat: set a breakpoint on A's "setflag" operation. When that breakpoint is reached, you can (a) look at what every thread is doing, and (b) freeze the threads you you like. but honestly, you can forget all about doing anything "at the moment" something happens. Calling a `SuspendThread`-like function takes time, and when it takes effect, the to-be-suspended thread has had pelnty of time to execute.

Comment: @jalf: I agree that I will not suspend the thread immediately, but having to manually suspend a thread is just not developer-friendly.

Comment: No, but skewing your results when debugging threaded code isn't exactly developer-friendly either. What you're doing just doesn't make much sense. It won't tell you what thread B is doing when thread A is in any specific state

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is. In the proposed solution, thread B stops in the loops where we forgot to check the flag, so it stops when we need it to. The skewing is not relevant, because it might execute a bit longer, but it still halts in the relevant loops. The solution where we freeze manually just does not work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the system.  Windows has a function `SuspendThread`, but I'll admit that I don't know much about it.  Under Unix, you should be able to send a signal to the thread using `pthread_kill` (which despite its name, doesn't kill the thread, but just sends a signal), and catch it in the targeted thread, where the signal handler can call `sleep`.

Comment: `SuspendThread()` is great, but someone will have to call `ResumeThread()` later on or the thread will be suspended forever.

Comment: @sharptooth That someone should be the thread A, since it suspended it, no?

Comment: @VJovic: Yes, but it can forget to do so. It would be great if there was a function to suspend another thread for a specific amount of time so that it is autoresumed. I'm not aware of any.

Comment: @sharptooth Does the resume have to come from the same thread?  If not, you could start a second thread when you do the suspend, which sleeps for the desired interval, then does the resume.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @JamesKanze! 
In the hope to get it portable, i now have
`kill(B.native_handle(), SIGINT);`
Any thoughts on whether it will always work?

And indeed, B could spawn a timing thread, but as it is mainly for debugging, this is not essential.

Comment: @BroesDeCat I doubt that you can get it portable.  Under Unix, use `pthread_kill`, and not `kill`, to ensure that the correct thread gets the signal.  And I'd use some signal that doesn't have a predefined meaning: `SIGINT` is what the console will send if you enter control-C.  (`SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2` should be preferred.)